# Проверить, что строка - число

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Всем привет. Возник вопрос касаемо более красивой реализации проверки того, является ли строка числом.

Суть проблемы: Допустим, у нас есть строки "123", "12.3", "нестрока". Как нам проверить, что строка - это число? Есть метод TryParse. Но писать (код ниже) - как-то даже визуально выглядит не очень:

```
if (int.TryParse(AnyString, out _))
    return true;
else if (double.TryParse(AnyString, out _))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Может есть какой-то более красивый способ проверить это?

Comment: `return double.TryParse(AnyString, out _);`

Comment: Либо можете регуляркой проверить

Comment: NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture нужно в таком случае вводить? (я про 1 вариант)

Comment: `else if` вы можете перенести в первый `if`. `if(int.TryParse() || double.TryParse)`

Comment: @Frehzy, ну какой там у вас формат, вам виднее

Comment: Спасибо. Решено

Comment: @Frehzy, напишите свое решение ответом

Comment: @Aarnihauta, а по-твоему int не парсится в double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return double.TryParse(AnyString, out _, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так попробовать

```
   static bool IsNumeric(string targetStr, char sepDouble)
    {

        if (targetStr.Length == 1 && Char.IsDigit(targetStr[0]))
            return true;
        bool isSepDouble = false;
        if (targetStr.Length > 1 && targetStr[0] == '-')
            targetStr = targetStr.Substring(1);
        foreach (var sign in targetStr)
        {
            if (sign == sepDouble && !isSepDouble)
            {
                isSepDouble = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (isSepDouble && sign == sepDouble)
                return false;

            if (!Char.IsDigit(sign))
                return false;
        }
        if (isSepDouble && targetStr.Length == 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133098/discussion-on-answer-by-yury-bakharev----).

Comment: `IsNumeric("aaaaa!!", '.') -> true`. И еще - IsDigit выдает true на всяких там индийских цифрах типа '१' так что проверка сомнительная :(

Comment: @PashaPash поправил, но надо еще тестеров! Уже близок к удалению ответа;)

Comment: На вскидку - ещё с разделителем разрядов упадет